# Howto work with JSON in PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

1. I have a form where users can click a selection of a dropdown-box.
2. Depending on that selection a group of names must be shown.

I believe step 1 is best to be done in AJAX but what about step 2.
After reading a lot on the internet I believe the best way is using a JSON-object. Is this the best way?

Can somebody explain me how make this work?

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? Do you have working AJAX code? If so, can you post it?

Comment: You start by trying something, seeing what is up with what you tried then asking why it went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a `POST` request with the input parameters via AJAX, then return an array of JSON objects from the PHP function your AJAX request calls (JSON is very easy to parse in JavaScript).

Something like (assuming using jQuery):

```
$.post('somepage.php',{'age':'18'},function(data,status){
    if (data instanceof Array) {
        // Clear the display div
        $('#displayDiv').html('');
        // Append all the items to the div
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('#displayDiv').append('<p>'+data[i].firstName+' '+data[i].lastName+'</p>');
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: After reading a lot on the net and the answer of Lightning Dust it's now completely clear .... and working :D

Answer (score 0):

So if your list of names is on a file in your server, you have a .php file that accepts requests and you use AJAX to submit the right GET.

In your javascript using jquery, do something like

```
$.getJSON("names.php", {n:choice})
```

and in your php, do

```
$n=strtolower($_GET["n"]);
```

do whatever you need in your code, then eventually

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

and then you do whatever you want with the JSON object, which can be handled like any other js array.